# Access a resource name programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have many string arrays in my resource files, and I want to access them programmatically depending on user input.

```
int c = Getter.getCurrentNumber();
String[] info = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.n_<c>);
```

So if c==12, info should be the string-array with name "n_12".
Is there a way to do this, and avoiding to do a switch statement with hundreds of cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the resource id like so

```
int c = Getter.getCurrentNumber();
String resource = "n_" + c;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(resource, "array", "com.your.project");
```

Then just use that id

```
String[] info = getResources().getStringArray(id);
```

Have a look [here](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=17846) for another example on `getResources().getIdentifier()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a resource by name (programmatically) and you are not sure how to address the resource by name (but you do know how to access it by R.), you can do this:

- First print the exact resource name, like this:

`Log.d("", context.getResources().getResourceName(R.id.whichYouAlreadyKnow) );`

(Note: R.id.whichYouAlreadyKnow can be R.string.*  R.drawable.* etc...) 
Now you know the exact Resource address name

- Take the printed name and use it as is, like this:

`int id = getResources().getIdentifier(resource_name_that_printed_above, null, null);`

Cheers