# Get resource id from string

Tags: java, android, integer, android-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access a resource name programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999866/access-a-resource-name-programmatically)

I'm trying to set a drawable id with a string, but it doesn't work..

So i tried this:

```
String NoteString = "R.drawable.notebackground".toString();

remoteviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, context.getResources().getIdentifier(NoteString, "drawable", "com.example.MY-PACKAGE-NAME"));
```

but the image doesn't appear.

if i say this it works:

```
remoteviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, R.drawable.notebackground);
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Why don't you ensure that its returning the image bitmap just to ensure nothing is wrong with your R.java

Comment: @JoxTraex Didn't know I should, I'm a beginner, how would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
remoteviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, getResources().getIdentifier(imageFilename, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: i get an error on getResources() saying: The method getResources() is undefined for the type Widget, why??

Comment: thanks, the errors's gone, but the background image doesn't appear, but if i just set it to this, it works views.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, R.drawable.notebackground);

Comment: @Jakob : `Context.getResources` means `your_current_activity.this.getResources`