# How Can I get R.id.'X' with android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have at least 100 arraylist on my strings folder.And I want to get random arraylist from strings folder.Im trying to use this code ;

```
int choosen= r.nextInt(1-2);
String [] choose1= {"question1","question2"};

String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.choose1[choosen]);
```

my arraylist's name is same with choose1 values.Can anyone help ?

Comment: Is this related to the R statistical environment? If not, then please remove that tag.

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999866/access-a-resource-name-programmatically ?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov thank u I think this works for me.